# How to open website link with parameter instead using of Form in jquery?

Tags: jquery

"cmd" and "hosted_button_id" are name of input box.

I don't like to use Form then change to jquery

$.post('https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr',{cmd:'_s-xclick',hosted_button_id:'LWFDKCLKLEE'});

Hi,
     I can't fingure out this way. I like to open new link with parameter in jquery. I check something before this line.
    Thanks. Please help me out.

Answer (score 2):

You can't make cross-domain ajax calls without using something like `JSONP`.  See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: I try this $.ajax({ type: "POST", url: "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr", data: "cmd=_s-xclick&hosted_button_id='LWFDKCLKLEE'", success: function(msg){ //alert( "Data Saved: " + msg ); } });
it doesn't work out.

Comment: Thanks. I change direction. below is what I have done. 
 $('body').append($('<form/>')              .attr({'action': 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr', 'method': 'post', 'id': 'btn_submit'})                       .append($('<input/>')                          .attr({'type': 'hidden', 'name': 'cmd', 'value': "_s-xclick"})   )                       .append($('<input/>')                         .attr({'type': 'hidden', 'name': 'hosted_button_id', 'value': "SDFSDFFGHFGH"})                        )                      ).find('#btn_submit').submit();